# SSIS package runs fine but SQL Server job fails

Tags: sql, ssis

I am having a package which is loading one of my table of database. When I run the SSIS package individually the package is running fine at first. But when I execute the job on SQL, the job fails & the database table records becomes empty.

After that the SSIS package also fails to run. The cause of job failure is giving primary key violation for that table. The package is simply importing the data to this table.

Comment: You'll need to post more info than that to get assistance (i.e., what is the SSIS package doing, steps, etc)

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem running your ssis twice, independently of **how** you execute it. If its a primary key error, most likely you are trying to load data that already exists on your table, but we need far more details to actually help you with a proper answer

Comment: @Lamak thanks for your concern, but the thing is if it is doing the thing twice then why am getting empty table after job fails

Comment: @Neha - That's why I said that we need more details about the package. How is the data flow configured?, maybe the data that you want to import is duplicated and you have your package make it so it first delete the data and then insert it, we don't know

Comment: But the same thing I have copied from production server where it is working

Comment: @Neha - Then it may be a problem with your local database, there is nothing else that is different?

Comment: I restored the production DB to my dev

Comment: This may seem a silly question, but you aren't loading this local data into *production* are you? I read that this package was copied from production. If your connection managers are pointing to localhost, it's probably not an issue but if they were pointed at ProdServerA and no configurations are applied, you might have some cleanup on your hands.  Please update the question with the following information. Connection Managers, what are you using and where do they go? Configuration or Agent job settings: using them? Screen shot of the control flow & Data flow(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you be more specific? 
As I understood its not a SSIS package error, it seems to be a data issue.

I suggest checking if the package has any configuration assigned to it (right click the package on an empty area and select "pacakge configurations") because if it does, it ignores the hard coded values and overwrite them with the one on the config.

Comment: actually the same work is done for production & there it is working fine. I have copy the ssis packages to my local with restoring production database to my dev server.But on here it is giving this error

Comment: Thanks Diego, Yes the problem I found is with data of configured Excel. Instead of replacing it merged the records causing duplicate entries.